# Icons/Symbols according to GDPR

Tags: legal, eu-data-protection

According to Article 12(7) of the [European General Data Protection Regulation 2016/679](http://data.europa.eu/eli/reg/2016/679/oj) there shall be *standard icons* for making data collection more transparent for data subjects (end users):

> 7. The information to be provided to data subjects pursuant to
>      Articles 13 and 14 may be provided in combination with standardised
>      icons in order to give in an easily visible, intelligible and clearly
>      legible manner a meaningful overview of the intended processing. Where
>      the icons are presented electronically they shall be machine-readable.

With 12(8) the EC is empowered to make the decision making, and with Article 7 (1r) The (new) European Data Protection Board is asked to provide input in this process. The EC must present the delegated act to EP and Council and only if they do not object within 3 month this can go into effect.

As the EDP Board is not yet formed and the (old) Article 29 Working Party currently seems not to work on the icon sets, I wonder if anybody already knows about work in progress or a roadmap. Will the EC start this process, if so what feed to follow to be informed about it?

Comment: The Art29 WP acknowledges the need to develop the icons, but looks like there are no quick results to be expected http://ec.europa.eu/newsroom/article29/document.cfm?doc_id=50057#page22

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're just looking for the best RSS feeds for the latest info? In that case consider https://packetstormsecurity.com/feeds

More specifically, for your needs, I recommend following:

- https://rss.packetstormsecurity.com/news/tags/goverment/
- https://rss.packetstormsecurity.com/news/

Or just follow http://world.einnews.com/news/europe-security 's RSS feed.

**EDUT:** In regard to the first part of your Q - I do not know about the proceedings. I just gave you a list of feeds to follow if you'd like to stay updated. If anyone is able to give you a better answer, pick the other one.

Comment: Thank you for stepping in. I guess a more focused feed would be to follow all EC updates, but that might be a bit overkill as it is such a large organisation and its not clear to me which branch would be responsible. I am looking more for a actual EU document showing the roadmap or the recommendation or task list.